# Failed creating starting window on Android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have been getting this error for a week and I have no idea that caused this error. The game works on unity editor with no problem. As soon as Unity builds and runs the game on the Android device, the game crashes with this log.

```
03-26 19:14:40.070 815-931/? W/WindowManager: Token{44bfbbb8 ActivityRecord{45526c08 u0 com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t388}} failed creating starting window
                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #31: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
                                          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:492)
                                          at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6204)
                                          at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6372)
                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1837)
                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1749)
                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:58)
                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:768)
                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                                          at      com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3315)
                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3378)
                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1870)
                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.addStartingWindow(PhoneWindowManager.java:2753)
                                          at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:9440)
                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
03-26 19:14:40.310 13526-13526/? D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester-3/lib/libmain.so 0x42609060
03-26 19:14:40.320 13526-13526/? D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester-3/lib/libmain.so 0x42609060
03-26 19:14:42.260 12435-13607/? D/PkgBroadcastIntentOp: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester
03-26 19:14:42.430 12435-13607/? D/WearableController: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester
03-26 19:14:42.590 12435-13628/? D/gH_MetricsDatabase: 0 metrics were deleted when clearing package com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester.
03-26 19:14:42.870 815-2343/? D/ThermalMonitor: Foreground Application Changed: com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester
03-26 19:14:44.600 13526-13590/? E/Unity: Invalid serialized file version. File: "/mnt/asec/com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester-3/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/globalgamemanagers". Expected version: 5.3.1f1. Actual version: 5.3.2f1.

                                  (Filename:  Line: 1045)
03-26 19:14:44.850 815-8185/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{449735a8 u0 com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
03-26 19:14:44.850 815-1260/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester (pid 13526) (adj 0) has died.
03-26 19:14:44.850 815-8185/? W/WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{4559ea18 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{449735a8 u0 com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
03-26 19:14:44.850 815-1260/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{45526c08 u0 com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t388}: app died, no saved state
03-26 19:14:47.110 12435-13607/? D/PkgBroadcastIntentOp: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester
03-26 19:14:47.540 12435-13607/? D/WearableController: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester
03-26 19:14:47.580 12435-13992/? D/k: Processing package: com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester
03-26 19:14:47.630 13592-13964/? I/UpdateIcingCorporaServi: Updating corpora: APPS=com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester, CONTACTS=MAYBE
03-26 19:14:47.660 12435-13992/? D/GassUtils: Found app info for package com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester:2. Hash: 697d83f55dab21db6f0e7a85ee05325dacc575c7cb6660ae4d7751cc1670d845
03-26 19:14:47.660 12435-13992/? D/k: Found info for package com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester in db.
03-26 19:14:48.290 14009-14072/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester.YPLContentProvider
03-26 19:14:49.140 12435-13607/? D/PkgBroadcastIntentOp: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED and uri=com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester
03-26 19:14:49.160 12435-14179/? D/k: Processing package: com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester
03-26 19:14:49.190 12435-14179/? D/GassUtils: Found app info for package com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester:2. Hash: 697d83f55dab21db6f0e7a85ee05325dacc575c7cb6660ae4d7751cc1670d845
03-26 19:14:49.190 12435-14179/? D/k: Found info for package com.akkuzugames.flip.flop.reflex.tester in db.
```

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know what was the problem but I finally solved my problem uninstalling Unity and its components by using AppCleaner, and re-installing.